# Maximum size and bandwidth of SE "voting telegraphy"? Is this a known thing?

Tags: discussion

Several months ago I was looking at one of my posts, and I noticed an up vote started to toggle. The vote count incremented by one, then decremented again, cyclicly. At my end the rate seemed faster than 2 Hz, and the toggling continued for several seconds. Say 10 full up-down cycles in all, as a short burst.

It felt a bit spooky, as if someone was trying to "send me a message" and that's weird because there's never been a case of non-verbal communication in SE ;-)

I'm wondering if there is an upper limit to the rate at which someone can indecisively toggle an up vote, or on the total number of toggles, before SE bots say "that's enough", or a limit on what people on the other end see?

Because of the way packets route, I assume this can't be easily used to send secret messages without sever corruption because the timing information is lost, at least as far as the viewer sees on the screen.

Is this a "known thing" and I'm just the last person to find out?

Comment: A user can vote and un-vote on a post up to 30 times; after that, they can't vote on it anymore.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog got it, all good, thank you.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog [I've just been reminded of the limit](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/are-i-suspect-answers-okay-what-if-we-all-started-writing-them#comment6103_1652) again recently. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxkwI.png