# Does a blinking +10 ("voting telegraphy") mean anything more than someone is just screwing around?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, user-interface, notifications

[Maximum size and bandwidth of SE "voting telegraphy"? Is this a known thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317614/303080) was closed as duplicate of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/303080) and basically one can change their vote 30 times before it freezes.

But it happened to me again, just moments ago. So now I'm wondering

**Question:** Does a blinking +10 ("voting telegraphy") mean anything more than someone is just screwing around?

Is there anything in the depths of SE software that might cause a green +10 to turn on and off at roughly 1 Hz for say ten full cycles then stay off for a while? Anything at all? Maybe some leftover debugging test?

Or can one be sure that it's someone just screwing around?

I get a lot of views per day network-wide so if it happens then I'm a likely recipient statistically speaking.

I tried to click it to see which post it might be coming from but it doesn't appear that the list of recent reputation changes updated fast enough to capture it while it was still in a state of flux.

---

The green +1 on the right blinks on and off at about 1 Hz:

[image]

Comment: I think you can find the affected post(s) through the API: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/377214

Comment: It is almost certainly someone screwing around. I’d software got stuck in an oscillating pattern it’d go **much** faster than about 1Hz.

Comment: If updates to the page were blocked (I've seen this with an open alert/confirm popup) then releasing the block will process all events that have been waiting. So, if you had a page "stuck" and in the mean time you got an upvote, then cleared it, then got another, then cleared it, etc., finally went back to the "stuck" page and unblocked it, then you'd see flashing and disappearing +10. That's assuming you had a page that was stuck for a while.